# Get information in two steps with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to get some information from the user in two steps with javascript.
The user will provide this information by clicking on two different buttons.

I am struggling with the fact that the two actions (button clicks) will be triggered separately. Each time I will get a piece of information and I can do the magic only when I have both pieces.

This is what I tried (simplified to get to the core of my problem):

HTML

```
<div class="container-1">
    <button class="my-btn" id="red">
        Color1
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="green">
        Color2
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="blue">
        Color3
    </button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container-2">
    <button class="my-btn" id="dog">
        Animal1
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="cat">
        Animal2
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="mouse">
        Animal3
    </button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
sumUp = function(data) {
  first = data.btn1;
  second = data.btn2;
  alert('You chose a ' + first + ' ' + second);
};
$(".my-btn").click(function() {
  var val1 = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".container-2 .my-btn").click(function() {
    var val2 = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  var data = {
    btn1: val1,
    btn2: val2
  };
  sumUp(data);
});
```

[This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/310an3ds/1/) will help to understand better what I am trying. It could be assumed that first the color would always be selected and then the animal.

In this example, I would just need to get the alert saying "You chose a red cat", or whatever combination depending on the buttons clicked.

What am I doing wrong and how could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues. First off, you're binding a new click handler every time you click `.my-btn`. You only want one binding and reuse it. Next, you need to store your state somewhere between clicks. A simple object would work fine for this.

```js
let choices = {
  color: null,
  animal: null
};

function useChoices() {
  // Don't do anything if the user hasn't selected a value
  // from both categories
  if (choices.color === null || choices.animal === null) {
    return;
  }
  
  alert('You are a ' + choices.color + ' ' + choices.animal);
}

$('.color').click(function() {
  // Save the selected color
  choices.color = $(this).val();
  
  // Attempt to use the combined data
  useChoices();
});

$('.animal').click(function() {
  // Save the selected animal
  choices.animal = $(this).val();
  
  // Attempt to use the combined data
  useChoices();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="color" value="red">Red</button>
<button class="color" value="green">Green</button>
<button class="color" value="blue">Blue</button>
<br />
<button class="animal" value="cat">Cat</button>
<button class="animal" value="dog">Dog</button>
<button class="animal" value="bird">Bird</button>
```

You could have just saved your choices in independent variables rather than an object but by putting them inside of an object, you never have to worry about re-using that variable name somewhere else.

Comment: Would it make sense to add `choices.color = null;` and `choices.animal = null;` after the alert to restart the variables once the message has been displayed?

Comment: I am trying to replicate this proposal in my jsfiddle, but I am getting a message with the variables empty... Any idea of why this could be?

Comment: I got it, you change `.attr('id')` for `.val()`. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/310an3ds/2/) the jsfiddle working following your proposal :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put `data` and `sumUp()` inside the `.container-2` click handler callback function. Also, make sure you are using `.off()` on the `.container-2` click handler, so you do not register numerous handlers and have duplicate processing.

The reason you are able to access `val1` inside the `container-2` click handler callback is because of a concept called [JavaScript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```js
var sumUp = function(data) {
  first = data.btn1;
  second = data.btn2;
  alert('You chose a ' + first + ' ' + second);
};
$(".my-btn").click(function() {
  var val1 = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".container-2 .my-btn").off("click.myclick");
  $(".container-2 .my-btn").on("click.myclick", function() {
    var val2 = $(this).attr('id');
    var data = {
      btn1: val1,
      btn2: val2
    };
    sumUp(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-1">
    <button class="my-btn" id="red">
        Color1
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="green">
        Color2
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="blue">
        Color3
    </button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container-2">
    <button class="my-btn" id="dog">
        Animal1
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="cat">
        Animal2
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="mouse">
        Animal3
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The concept of Javascript Closures seems similar to global variables. Are they also so "dangerous"?

Comment: @J0ANMM Well, to answer that question, you must understand **why** global variables are dangerous. They are dangerous because you can overwrite other things (usually third-party library functions/variables). Closures simply allow a variable to be accessed outside of its lexical scope at run time, which is EXTREMELY powerful, and EXTREMELY useful. I would say that closures are probably in the top 3 most important things you can learn as a JS developer

Comment: It's clear now. Thanks a lot. I find both your answer and Mike's solving the problem. I will accept his answer just because he was faster to reply, but thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

This was the quickest solution I could come up with. There are other ways to do it, but this should just work and is easy to implement.

```
var option1, option2;

var run_alert = function() {
    if(option1.length && option2.length) {
        alert('You chose a ' + option1 + ' ' + option2);
    }
}

$(".container-1 .my-btn").click(function() {
    option1 = $(this).attr('id');
    run_alert();
});
$(".container-2 .my-btn").click(function() {
    option2 = $(this).attr('id');
    run_alert();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
   <div class="container-1">
    <button class="my-btn" id="red">
        Color1
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="green">
        Color2
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="blue">
        Color3
    </button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container-2">
    <button class="my-btn" id="dog">
        Animal1
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="cat">
        Animal2
    </button>
    <button class="my-btn" id="mouse">
        Animal3
    </button>
</div>
```

Javascript part

```
 DATA={
    color:"",
  animal:""
}

sumUp = function(data){
    first = DATA.color;
    second = DATA.animal;
    if(DATA.color != "" && DATA.animal !=""){
        alert('You chose a ' + first + ' ' + second);
    }

};

$(".container-2 .my-btn").click(function() {
        DATA.animal = $(this).attr('id');
    sumUp(DATA)
});
$(".container-1 .my-btn").click(function() {
        DATA.color = $(this).attr('id');
    sumUp(DATA)
});
```